# Shorten a repeating exit flag for functions

Tags: python, function, return, exit

I would like to exit a function by pressing a button using the `return` statement in the `if` statement. To write these lines again and again and again is not really what I like. That's why I am basically looking for a function that tells the parent function to `return`.

Obviously I can't use the `return` statement in a function and just execute the function where I want to check the variable, although that would be the nicest way I could imagine.

I want to explain it in a loop, but please keep in mind that's not where I want to use it. The usage is for automated processes which should have many exit points.

```
import keyboard, time

RedFlag = False
def set_RedFlag():
    global RedFlag
    RedFlag = True
keyboard.add_hotkey("end", set_RedFlag)

PauseFlag = False
def set_PauseFlag():
    global PauseFlag
    print(PauseFlag)
    if PauseFlag == False:
        PauseFlag = True
    else:
        PauseFlag = False
keyboard.add_hotkey("space", set_PauseFlag)

def task():
    for i in range(30):
        print("test",i)
        time.sleep(1)

        # Flags
        if RedFlag == True: # exitpoint
            return
        while PauseFlag == True: # pause the script
            time.sleep(1/6)
task()
```

Really relevant is the `if` statement after `#Flags`. Especially with the `while` statement I would have to repeat multiple lines. I would love to have this in one single word as if it was a function.

Edit:

More about the "what for?":
I would like to run a macro and later maybe other tasks. For example writing the odd numbers from 1 to 511. And I want to be able to stop or pause it at any given time.

I forgot to mention, that I tried using the multiprocessing module, since I could terminate the task there. Sadly it is not an option for me not only because the starting time of a process is a bit too long for me, also I am learning a bit about kivy and I know it get's complicated when I want to start another process while using kivy.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand your question.  As presented it seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) but since you're new to programming it might be there are some concepts you haven't heard of yet, so I understand if it's hard to know the right question to ask.  Instead of focusing on what you've done so far (which is still a good place to start a question!), maybe back up a bit and explain simply (without code) what your code is for and what behavior you want it to have.

Comment: I sort of understand that you have a `task()` function that you want to be able to stop or pause independently of the execution of the rest of your program.  Depending on the context there are many ways you might approach such a problem (threads, subprocesses, generators, coroutines, signals...)

Comment: I.e, it's the job of a *thread* to execute `task` as quickly as possible, while it's the job of the *thread scheduler* to decide when (if ever) the thread running `task` gets to execute.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of would be by raising an `Exception` of some kind which will cause a jump to the nearest enclosing `try` / `except` (or terminate the script if there isn't one). The only problem with that is it would kind of be abusing exception-handling since they're intended to be for when exceptional things happen (like errors), not for the normal processing of the code — although I've seen it done more than once.

Comment: @Iguananaut I would like to run a macro. Most likely I want to click and type using pyautogui and thus complete tasks. But I would like to be able to terminate the task incase of me suddenly having different plans or silmilar. I forgot to mention that I tried multiprocessing but I feel like the starting time of a process is a bit to long to use it for this. Since the threading module doesn't have the option to terminate a thread like a process in multiprocessing I can't see any way of using threads to solve this. Unfortunately I don't know much about subprocesses, generators, coroutines, ...

Comment: @chepner I am not quite familiar with thread scheduling. I forgot to mention that I tried using the multiprocessing module, since I could terminate the task there, but it is not an option for me not only since the starting time of a process is a bit too long for my comfort also I am learning a bit about kivy and I know it get's complicated if I want to start another process if I use kivy. Now I don't understand how scheduling a thread could help me with exiting a task or thread cleanly. And starting a thread for every block of code doesn't seem easier.

Comment: You don't return early from the function; you only kill the thread. Likewise, you don't call `sleep` in the thread, you just pause it and then resume it.